# nth-child not attributing when screen size is smaller

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is my relevant css (just the phone version. the difference from the computer version is the "(max-width : 1223px)" turns into "(min-width : 1224px)"):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
}

a:hover {
    color: blue;
}

section {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    /*padding: 40px 30px 37px 30px;*/
    padding-top: 3%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    padding-left: 2%;
}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1223px) {
    .logo {
        /*background: url(logo.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;*/
        background: url(http://i48.tinypic.com/2mob6nb.png);
        background-size: 140px 59px;
        width: 140px;
        height: 59px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2%;
        /* left: 405px; */
        left: 38%;
    }
    nav li:nth-child(2) {
        padding-right: 10%;
    }
    nav li:nth-child(3) {
        padding-left: 10%;
    }
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {
    .logo {
        /*background: url(logo.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;*/
        background: url(http://i48.tinypic.com/2mob6nb.png);
        background-size: 140px 59px;
        width: 140px;
        height: 59px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        /* left: 405px; */
        left: 44%;
    }
    nav li:nth-child(2) {
        padding-right: 10%;
    }
    nav li:nth-child(3) {
        padding-left: 10%;
    }
}

#sectionLeft {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

#section {
    width: 48%;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
}

#sectionLeft h2, #section h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#newsSection {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

#newsText {
    font-size: 12px;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 2.5%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -2px 2px 0px #ebebeb;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -2px 2px 0px #ebebeb;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 2px 0px #ebebeb;
    bottom: 0;
}

#footerText {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

and the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Aversion Gaming</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Teams</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                    <li>Sponsors</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </header>
    </section>

    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="sectionLeft">
            <h2>News</h2>
            <section id="newsSection">
                <h3>Test news post</h3>
                <p id="newsText">This is just a test news post.</p>
                <a style="font-size: 12px;" href="#">Read More...</a>
            </section>
            <section id="newsSection">
                <h3>Finally, a website!</h3>
                <p id="newsText">We have finally created a website thanks to
                    @AversionRastro!</p>
                <a style="font-size: 12px;" href="#">Read More...</a>
            </section>
        </div>

        <div id="section">
            <h2>About</h2>
            <section id="newsSection">
                <p id="newsText">
                    <b>Aversion Gaming</b> is a newly founded gaming organization.
                </p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p id="footerText">Copyright 2014 Aversion Gaming. Designed and
            coded by Robert Trainor.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page on my Windows 7 laptop, it shows the logo (got it from another post, so its just an example) and all of the formatting code in the @media works.
When I pin the browser to a side on the same computer, the code for the smaller window size doesn't kick in.

The logo never shows and the formatting for the 2nd and 3rd list items don't get their padding.

If there is something I'm missing or doing wrong here, please tell me.

Comment: Can you post the other css? It's probably having an impact on this scenario. Hence, it's relevant.

Comment: @MikeLoffland I edited the post with the entire stylesheet

Comment: And the accompanying HTML? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code and on my macbook with safari it works just fine (meaning in my browser the source code kicks in correctly by scaling down/up).

Have you checked if the code kicks in (so does it show up in your source code), or does it only not look as you wish?

You want to add the padding to the navigation to add additional white space next to the logo I guess, so that it looks a little bit more tidied up? If so my suggestions:

Currently your logo is not centered in mobile version. Thats the first point to make a little adjustment:

```
.logo {
  background: url(http://i48.tinypic.com/2mob6nb.png);
  background-size: 140px 59px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 59px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 50%; /* center the left side of the logo */
  margin-left: -70px; /* go half of the logos width backwards, so that the logos center is centered */
}
```

Then your `<li>`s receive the additional padding, but they are centered as text, not as "blocks". You can't the same amount of white space on the left and on the right side. To achieve this the next adjustment would be to add a `width`to your `<li>`s like so:

```
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3% 2%;
  width: 50px; /* change this to whatever you want in px or % */
}
```

The difference looks like this (first before, then after):

[image: before]
[image: after]

Does this fix your problem? If not feel free to correct my understanding of your question or let me know, if you need further information.

Best regards,
Marian.